# git push -f leave unwanted log in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I did a commit, pushed it, but later realised I made some mistake on the code, I do `git reset HEAD~`, and recommit and `push -f`, I found there's an extra log in my PR. How do I get rid of that?

Comment: what do you mean by "extra log in PR"? How does it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume here that the problem is that you actually made a *new* commit on top of your branch, instead of amending the commit you wanted to rework.  So here is what you probably should have done:

```
# make changes
git commit --amend
git push --force origin master
```

This should still leave you adding one new commit to the remote.  However, in general force pushing a branch is bad news in Git, especially when other users might be sharing your branch, and might have already pulled it at some point.  In this case, a much safer approach is to just make a new commit and push that.  Or, you could use `git revert` to undo a commit, if you wanted to do that.

Comment: @YunyiChang I disagree.  Amend can rewrite the entire commit you have in mind, _including_ the commit message.

Comment: hmm maybe, maybe I have to make changes and do commit --amend, but does it matter if I already pushed my mistaken codes?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a remote `origin` with branch `master` that currently points to commit `dd61ab32`. We want to remove the `top` commit. Translated to git terminology, we want to force the `master` branch of the origin remote repository to the `parent` of `dd61ab32`:

```
git push origin +dd61ab32^:master
```

Where git interprets `x^` as the parent of `x` and `+` as a forced non-fastforward push.

If it is the last commit that you wanted to delete locally then:
Two steps needed:

```
git reset HEAD^ --hard
git push origin -f
```

if its not the last commit you could try:

```
git rebase -i commit_hash^
```

Rewriting history or rebasing if the branch has already been pushed is usually a bad idea and you may also prefer to use:

```
git revert commit_hash
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/gunjanpatel/18f9e4d1eb609597c50c2118e416e6a6)

Answer (score -1):

You can untrack the file with:

```
git rm --cached <file_name>
```

Then you need to put it in the `.gitignore` file so you will not add it again.
If the file is created automatically and the name changes from build to build, you can use a wild card like `*.log` or `target/*`, for example.